# How to respond to receiving a duplicate list of corrections

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission

Two weeks ago I have done and I have submitted the corrections that a journal had asked me to do, but today thay asked me to do the same corrections. I am looking for a good letter cover to let them know.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the new version didn't arrive or they lost it. Perhaps the editor clicked the wrong link and sent you the wrong response. Write back that you made those corrections and sent them on *date*. Include a fresh copy of the new document. Ask for instructions on how to proceed if there is any difficulty.

I suspect it is just a simple error. Make a simple and friendly response.

Answer (score 2):

**Keep it brief and don't overthink it.** Do not go on and on to apologize, ask for what you have done wrong, etc., when it is mostly likely that this can be attributed to a simple mistake.

I agree with Buffy's suggestion; something like this seems appropriate:

> Dear [editor],
>
> We previously addressed the corrections to our article, and emailed them to [address] on [date] (see attached). Were you able to receive the corrections? Is there anything else that we can provide at this time?
>
> Thank you,
>
> [your name]